# Mixed shell and python script possible?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I swear I have seen this done before but can not find it now. Is it possible to have a shell script start a python interpeter "mid stream", ie:

```
#!/bin/bash
#shell stuff..

set +e

VAR=aabb

for i in a b c; do
    echo $i
done

# same file!

#!/usr/bin/env python
# python would be given this fd which has been seek'd to this point

import sys

print ("xyzzy")

sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this shell syntax (it is called *here document* in Unix literature):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo this is a shell script

python <<@@
print 'hello from Python!'
@@
```

The marker after '<<' operator can by an arbitrary identifier, people often use something like EOF (end of file) or EOD (end of document). If the marker starts a line then the shell interprets it as end of input for the program.

Answer (score 3):

If your `python` script is very short. You can pass it as a string to `python` using the `-c` option:

```
python -c 'import sys; print "xyzzy"; sys.exit(0)'
```

Or

```
python -c '
import sys
print("xyzzy")
sys.exit(0)
'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write

```
exec python <<END_OF_PYTHON

import sys

print ("xyzzy")

sys.exit(0)
END_OF_PYTHON
```

to replace the Bash process with Python and pass the specified program to Python on its standard input. (The `exec` replaces the Bash process. The `<<END_OF_PYTHON` causes standard input to contain everything up till `END_OF_PYTHON`.)

Comment: +1: as execing is superior to just invoking python.  The shebang is unnecessary in this context, and will be treated merely as a comment.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Y'know, I didn't even notice the shebang . . . not only is it unnecessary, but it's actually misleading, since this will not invoke `env`. I suppose the command could be `exec env python <<END_OF_PYTHON`, but it's probably better just to remove the shebang.

Answer (score 0):

Of course right after I posted this I remembered a way to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Shell

python <<EOF

import sys

print "Python"

sys.exit(0)

EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that mixing/mashing up can be quite a powerful technique - not only in scripting but also in command line (e.g. perl inliners have been proven to be very successful over time). So my small tip on another variation of one-liners (in addition to mentioned by kev) for mixed scripting in bash/python:

```
for VAR in $(echo 'import sys; print "x y z"; sys.exit(0)' | python -);do echo "$VAR"; done;
```

produces

```
x
y
z
```